# Express checkout button mozilla not opening popup window

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, sdk

Mozilla Firefox is not opening a pop up window when I click the PayPal button. The server is returning the JSON but Firefox displays on the active window. I have tried it in Chrome and it is working fine on Chrome.

```
paypal.Button.render({
    env: sandbox,
    commit: true,
    payment: function() {
        var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = 'https://example.org/paypal-accesstoken.html';
        return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)
                .then(function(data) {
                    return data.id;
                });
    },
    onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.redirect();
    },
    onCancel: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.redirect();
    },
    onError: function(err) {
        alert('Something went wrong. Please reload the page and try again.');
    }
}, '#paypal-button');
```

Comment: sorry for bad english

Comment: Which version of firefox?

Comment: 55.0.2 (32-bit)

Comment: my mistake 
i was using the button tag instead of div for id